# How can I prevent Internet Explorer from auto-completing two form fields with the same value?

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, google-chrome, autocomplete

One of my client's users is using auto-complete to fill out an address form, but for some reason it is auto-filling two fields with the same data - the Address Line 1 and Address Line 3 fields. Here's the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong>Address 1:</strong>
        <font color="red">
            *
        </font>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="addressLine1" id="addressLine1" type="text" maxlength="40" size="40" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong>Address 2:</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="addressLine2" type="text" value="" size="40" maxlength="40">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong>Address 3:</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="addressLine3" type="text" value="" size="35" maxlength="40">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tested this out and it did the same thing - it auto-filled "addressLine1" and "addressLine3" with my Address Line 1 saved value:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: What happens if you give the 2nd and 3rd address lines an `id` attribute as you have with the first one? It's non-standard, but you could try turning off autocomplete on the 2nd and 3rd lines by adding an `autocomplete="off"` to each of the inputs.

Comment: adding id attributes has no effect.

Comment: I'm going to dedicate some time to this today and hopefully come up with a solution. One funny thing is, I can see it happening in IE9 and NOT in Google Chrome, but the user is experiencing it in Chrome.